# Getting user ID instead of volunteer ID while joining tables in Laravel GraphQL search handler

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

When i join two tables in search handler there is a same column in both tables, i cannot access the value of left table
for example if there are two tables user and volunteers they both have id column when I write a search handler like this

```
$builder->join('users', 'volunteers.user_id', "=", "users.id")
  ->join('policies','volunteers.policy_id',"=","policies.id")
  ->where(function($q) use ($whereConditions){
      $q->where('users.first_name','like','%'.$whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'].'%');
      $q->orWhere('users.last_name','like','%'.$whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'].'%');
      $q->orWhere('policies.name','like','%'.$whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'].'%');
      $q->orWhere('volunteers.experiences','like','%'.$whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'].'%');
      $q->orWhere('volunteers.medical_facility','like','%'.$whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'].'%');
   });
```

and when i query, it will return user id as volunteer id

I want the volunteer id but I always get the user id. I hope the question is clear

Comment: `->addSelect('users.id as user_id','volunteers.id as volunteer_id');` can we add this to bifurcate both ?

Comment: i tried but doesnot work

Comment: post your full query in question, what is `$builder` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented your problem and the problem happened to me but I solved it by using `$builder->select('your columns')`.
[image: your code where the problem raise]

[image: here the solution]

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you need to make sure that you are using the correct column names in your join statement. If the volunteers table has a column named volunteer_id which represents the ID of a volunteer, you should update your code like this:

```
$builder->join('users', 'volunteers.volunteer_id', '=', 'users.id')
->join('policies', 'volunteers.policy_id', '=', 'policies.id')
->where(function ($q) use ($whereConditions) {
    $q->where('users.first_name', 'like', '%' . $whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'] . '%');
    $q->orWhere('users.last_name', 'like', '%' . $whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'] . '%');
    $q->orWhere('policies.name', 'like', '%' . $whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'] . '%');
    $q->orWhere('volunteers.experiences', 'like', '%' . $whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'] . '%');
    $q->orWhere('volunteers.medical_facility', 'like', '%' . $whereConditions['OR'][0]['value'] . '%');
});
```

In the above code, I assumed that the column volunteer_id exists in the volunteers table and represents the ID of a volunteer. Make sure to replace volunteer_id with the correct column name if it differs in your database schema.

By updating the join condition to use the correct column name, you should be able to retrieve the volunteer ID instead of the user ID in your query results.

Comment: Several of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).